# Benchmarking runtime of ajax requests

Tags: php, networking, benchmarking, firefox-developer-tools

I am encountering a strange problem, and most likely I do not understand something correctly. I have a website, which uses ajax requests to load different pages, to make it more application like.

I've noticed that the page load times, are rather high (1-3 seconds), and wanted to benchmark it, to notice where the problem is coming from. I was using Firefox's Developer Tools, and the Networking tab. When I clicked on my link, to load the page with the ajax request, I was checking the developer tools. Developer tools gave me the following timings on this request:

`Blocked 334ms, Connect 162ms, TLS 170ms, Wait 1183ms, Total 1860ms`

To my understanding, this means that, it took *334ms* for the request to being sent from the browser, because of other concurrent requests, it took *162ms* to connect to the server, another *170ms* went by for handshake and auth, and the response on the server was generated and sent in *1183ms*. Are these assumptions true?

Next, I've implemented a small timer in my PHP script, by placing the following code at the very beginning of the `.php` file executed, and the very end, respectively:

```
 // beginning
 $start = microtime(true);

 // end
 $end = microtime(true) - $start;
```

Next, I've outputed the `$end` variable, to see, how many seconds does my code run in, and the result was `0.356235252352`.

So what I gather from this, my script run in *~0.4* seconds, but if this is true, where did the rest of the wait time, the *1.1s* go?

**EDIT:** Okay, so we nailed it down to something with PHP or Apache, but I don't know what could it be. When requesting php scripts on the server, we receive a first-byte-time of 7-800 ms, while with any other script file, or html page, we get a 60-70ms first-byte time.:(

Comment: Might be a wait queue with your php server itself before it begins the php processing.

Comment: @IncredibleHat any ideas how I could debug this?

Comment: I'm not a good server guy ;) I offload those questions to our IT guy haha. I would look at the overall server load though, make sure its not getting slammed at the time you are benchmarking. Also try to limit as much in-between you and the server. Could be a faulty routing situation with much too much lag.

Comment: Also if you can, attempt your bench tests from multiple machines and networks. That way you get a better overall curve of results. Ask friends to test it too if they are on the other side of the country or world.

Comment: Okay, so we nailed it down to something with PHP or Apache, but I don't know what could it be. When requesting php scripts on the server, we receive a first-byte-time of 7-800 ms, while with any other script file, or html page, we get a 60-70ms first-byte time.:(

Comment: Can you maybe add how the server is set up?
Are you using mod_php, CGI or FPM?

Comment: I see PHP first-byte to take longer then first-byte of serving a static file as normal. Give us a hint on your configuration.