# Very slow execution of php scripts on the server

Tags: php, benchmarking

This question is related to my other question, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911665/benchmarking-runtime-of-ajax-requests?noredirect=1#comment84829932_48911665).

At first I tought that this is a networking problem, but it seems more and more likely, that this has something to do with my php configuration, and the running of the php files. I've made the following test cases:

I've created a php file, named it `test.php`, with the following content:

```
 <?php
 echo 'test';
 ?>
```

and created two bash files, with the following contents:

```
//bash1.sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php /testFirstByte/test.php
```

and the other with

```
//bash2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Test;
```

Then I proceeded to time their run, running each and preceeding it with the 'time' command, ie: `time php test.php`

The results are as follows:

```
 // time php test.php
 test
 real    0m0.548s
 user    0m0.445s
 sys     0m0.101s
```

```
 // time sh bash2.hs
 Test
 real    0m0.002s
 user    0m0.002s
 sys     0m0.000s
```

```
 // time sh bash1.hs
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
 Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 test
 real    0m0.539s
 user    0m0.429s
 sys     0m0.108s
```

For me it looks like, that whenever I try to run a PHP script, the runtime is increased with at least half a second, for whichever php script I try to run. I can't figure out how to resolve this issue, so any help would be greatly appreaciated!

**EDIT 1:** I've made a simple script, I hope this is what you meant by the inside test @Eineki. The script is as follows:

```
$timer = microtime(true);
require('test_simple.php');
$end = microtime(true) - $timer;
echo "Require test duration was: " . $end . " seconds\n";

$timer = microtime(true);
exec('php test_simple.php');
$end = microtime(true) - $timer;
echo "Exec test duration was: " . $end . " seconds\n";
```

The results were as follows:

> Require test duration was: 0.00102400779724 seconds
>   Exec test duration was: 0.61318397522 seconds

**EDIT 2:** the list of loaded extensions are as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => sqlite3
    [7] => zlib
    [8] => bcmath
    [9] => bz2
    [10] => calendar
    [11] => ctype
    [12] => curl
    [13] => dom
    [14] => hash
    [15] => fileinfo
    [16] => filter
    [17] => ftp
    [18] => gd
    [19] => gettext
    [20] => SPL
    [21] => iconv
    [22] => session
    [23] => json
    [24] => mbstring
    [25] => mcrypt
    [26] => standard
    [27] => mysql
    [28] => mysqli
    [29] => mysqlnd
    [30] => Phar
    [31] => posix
    [32] => Reflection
    [33] => imap
    [34] => SimpleXML
    [35] => sockets
    [36] => exif
    [37] => tokenizer
    [38] => xml
    [39] => xmlreader
    [40] => xmlwriter
    [41] => zip
    [42] => cgi-fcgi
    [43] => PDO
    [44] => pdo_sqlite
    [45] => pdo_mysql
    [46] => mailparse
    [47] => Zend OPcache
)
```

And this is my php version, as of `php -v`:

```
PHP 5.5.30 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Dec  3 2015 06:55:27)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend    Technologies
```

**EDIT 3:** Run an `strace` as suggested by @voter on the php file, both on the production server (the server in question), and on our development server, where this problem does not occur. Everything that `strace` outputs is basically 10 times more on the prod server, then on the dev server. Maybe someone familiar with `strace` can gather a conclusion from this?

**EDIT 4:**

Exceprt from `vmstat 1` command:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 5  0 3163644 5410932 2522564 13417292    0    1    22    62    1    0 18  6 75  1  0   
 2  0 3163644 5845884 2522568 13406468    0    0     0   916 31787 5966  9  6 85  0  0  
 8  0 3163644 5439468 2522572 13406840    0    0     8   432 50513 5322 12  6 82  0  0  
 4  0 3163644 5750124 2522572 13407624    0    0     4   232 54417 5615  8  7 86  0  0  
 4  0 3163644 5748608 2522576 13407480    0    0     4   760 118206 5736  7  9 83  0  0 
 3  0 3163644 5742648 2522576 13418040    0    0     0   244 68462 6689 10  7 83  0  0  
 4  0 3163644 5671104 2522576 13407620    0    0    40   568 34157 4222  7  5 87  0  0  
 4  0 3163644 5980828 2522580 13401712    0    0    16   524 43754 6391 17  6 77  0  0  
 5  0 3163644 5506988 2522592 13418868    0    0   264   280 59452 5955 16  7 77  0  0  
 5  0 3163644 5577116 2522600 13417800    0    0    32   540 68056 8968 11  6 83  0  0  
 7  0 3163644 4747580 2522612 13451468    0    0    16   376 241800 7107 12 13 75  0  0 
 4  0 3163644 4948548 2522616 13440832    0    0    12   468 354599 5155  7 16 77  0  0
```

**EDIT 5:**

The results of a `top` command on the server:

```
top - 09:17:58 up 15 days,  1:53,  8 users,  load average: 6.90, 6.22, 5.34
Tasks: 687 total,   3 running, 683 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 15.0%us,  3.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.7%id,  0.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  49390000k total, 43364688k used,  6025312k free,  2697344k buffers
Swap: 16482300k total,  3495772k used, 12986528k free, 11878096k cached
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/php /testFirstByte/test.php` is CLI though, not Apache

Comment: yes, realized this after I wrote my question. So now it's nailed down to something related to php, but what could it be?:)

Comment: If you can, try upgrading to PHP7

Comment: @kerbholz I would only do that as a last resort:( unfortunately, the server in question is already in production, and I would not dare upgrading without pulling it down, plus this could take a lot of time:( if everything else fails, we will definitely get to there, but in the meantime, I am hoping that I will find a solution that doesn't require upgrading

Comment: Hmmm, something being "auto included"? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: @kerbholz doesn't look like it:( `auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =`

Comment: I have both 5.6 and 7.1 CLI installed and they're both in the range of 0,01s - 0,03s when running "your" script, maybe you could try to install 7.1 in parallel (don't blame me if you screw up your prod server ;)). Also, `php -v` shows "with Zend OPcache...", maybe your PHP is missing OPcache (don't know if that's even possible, stab in the dark). Good luck

Comment: @kerbholz this could be the problem, at the development server, it indeed misses Zend OPcache

Comment: @kerbholz  --- enabled Zend OPcache, but the problem still persists:(

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Half a second seems a lot of time to me, but without a phpinfo dump, at least, the best I can do is waste your time (and mine) with blind guesses.  - Have you xdebug in place to profile your execution time? There is something that your php interpreter (cli + cgi) wait before starting execution?  - Can you try to launch your tests within a php file: the first one with an require, the second one with a system , in order to level the starting condition and see if the delay is dued to the php environment loading time?  - Have you tried to call the php interpreter using his full path?

Comment: @Eineki did the last thing you asked (see question edit), it seems that while running the file from inside a php file with either `exec` or `system` command, the half second delay is again added. As the `phpinfo()` is too long, what informations would you need from it? I can gladly provide them

Comment: Please share the output from `php -i`

Comment: @AdamBaranyai the loaded extensions would be fine. I just read the installation is on a production server adn php_info. expose way too valuable informations on the server. --- Other tests in bash: `time php -v` to see how long it take to just load the interpreter. Try also with full path.

Comment: @Eineki run the requested bash script, both with full path, and local path, the times are the same: `real    0m0.741s    user    0m0.600s    sys     0m0.140s`. Btw, updated the question with my php version, and the list of loaded extensions.

Comment: @Greg as the info is very long, and this is a production server, I wouldn't want to share the whole phpinfo(). Please state what interests you from it, and I will copy it here, thanks:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai You may get hint of what is happening with tracing syscalls: strace -fr -o trace.txt  sh bash1.sh

Comment: @voter what I could gather from the `strace`, comparing the output to the output of one of our development servers, where this problem does not exist, that the exact same `strace` function on two exactly same `php` files, do seemingly the same, yet on the production server, everything takes around 10 times longer then on the dev server:( maybe someone who is familiar with strace can gather a conclusion from this, but I can't:(

Comment: Did you check if `opcache` is enabled for cli in your php.ini? `opcache.enable_cli=1`

Comment: @AdamBaranya If strace shows that everything is slower then it would be good to check server health and workload. Difficult to be specific - there are lot of things what could be wrong. You can try to look at "vmstat 1" to find your server cpu utilisation (id - idle time), swap and io load. Or if you are using raid look at its status "cat /proc/mdstat".

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo yes, opcache is enabled both in cli mode, and in default mode also.

Comment: @voter updated the question with an excerpt from the `vmstat 1` command, cause I don't really understand the data in there:( What I could gather is that idle time seems ok. I also checked with `top i` and that also shows that everything seems to be normal. But anyways, if the issue would be server related, wouldn't every other command lag also?

Comment: You are doing wrong at comparing bash to php execution times. Anyway, half a second is indeed really high. I may ask, how many CPU does your prod server have? What's the load average? You can use `top` or `htop` to check on this. How many php processes are running? You can use `ps aux` and `grep` to get it.

Comment: @MarcoFlorian When I tested with `ps aux`, there were 15 php processes running. I copied the top part of the results of a `top` command in the question. The testing part was only to compare other commands run duration, I do not want to get the same results with a php script that I get with a bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found what was causing the issue: it was one of the extensions, namely, the `browsecap` extension, or more likely, the lack of it.

At some point, it was installed, but when we realized, we wouldn't use it, for different kind of reasons, we uninstalled it, yet it wasn't removed from the `php.ini` file. By removing a single line related to `browsecap` from the ini file, the problem solved completly.

I would like to thank @Pampy for pointing me in the right direction, with the extensions. If anyone experiences something simmilar in the future, an option to debug if the problem is simmilar, is to run php from the command line, with the `-n` parameter, which actually disables it's ini, and all the loaded extensions at once.

Answer (score 5):

Your `php -v` output looks like you're calling php cgi from the command line.

For the command line, there's usually a CLI version of php, which can be installed separately, e.g. `apt-get install php5-cli`.

This can have a quite big impact on performance. A quick test on a medium-sizes linux server gives me

```
#time php-cgi test.php
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26
Content-type: text/html

test
real    0m0.117s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.076s

# time php test.php
test
real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.036s
```

As you can see, the time for the cgi version is doubled.
Can you try with the CLI version instead to see if the difference is still that big?

That probably won't help you with the question in the other thread you mentioned, unless you're also using the CGI module there and didn't configure it correctly.

Comment: I am getting almost the same results with both the cli version, and the non-cli one. The cli version is around 0.05s slower then the non-cli one. Times with `time php-cli simple_test.php` are as follows: `test
real    0m0.652s
user    0m0.529s
sys     0m0.122s`

Comment: Maybe a new idea: Did you already try do disable some of your extensions to see if one of them is causing the problem?
If you google for it, you'll find that some persons had problems with certain extensions slowing down PHP for some reasons, e.g. the imap extension here https://github.com/liip/build-entropy-php/issues/11 or the curl extension here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528371/slow-php-command-line-performance-is-this-normal-or-do-i-have-an-install-probl

Comment: Googling a bit more, maybe you need to add your hostname in /etc/hosts according to this entry here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/php-from-the-terminal-running-very-slow-on-new-mac?page=1

Comment: didn't tried any of those yet, will try it a bit later, and report back with the results, thanks

Comment: thanks for the help, the problem was with one of the extensions

Answer (score 0):

for me this works fine.

```
/usr/bin/php -q script.php > /dev/null &
```

give it a try, I would like to see the results on your configuration. Since it is command line triggered, I suspect you do not need output. you can send input as arguments.

Comment: anyway, in my opinion, there is no parallel in testing a bash echo and compare it with running an interpreted php script.

Comment: It seems that you guys are missing the point entirely. I have nothing to do with exec, neither require, those were just simple tests I did, on behalf of a commenter on the original quesiton. The problem is, that each time I run a php script, there is a 0.5s overhead. Even if the script does NOTHING at all. That is my problem, and that is what I am looking a solution for.